# LSTM autoencoder dimensionality reduction constant output

Tags: keras, lstm, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to embed a dataset of variable-size sequences of integer in fixed length vectors using a LSTM autoencoder but the model continues to output constant vector even if the sequences are different.

Each sample of the dataset is expressed as following:

### [1,3,4,2,1]

Each sequence is encoded using one-hot encoding:

### [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]

In case of shorter sequences zero-padding is applied to the one-hot encoded vector.

### [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],...,[0,0,0,0,0]]

At the end I have as input a matrix of size

### N_SAMPLES x N_INTEGERS(n_timesteps) X ONE_HOT_ENCODING_SIZE(n_features)

What I expect as output from the model is a matrix of size

### N_SAMPLES x FIXED_SIZE(latent_dim)

```py
from keras.utils import Sequence

def to_categorical(sequences, n_categories, max_len):
    categorical_sequences = []
    for s in sequences:
        #ohe = np.full((max_len, n_categories), fill_value=-1 )
        ohe = np.zeros((max_len, n_categories))
        for i, item in enumerate(s):
                ohe[i][item] = 1
        categorical_sequences.append(ohe)
    return np.array(categorical_sequences)

class batch_generator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, X, batch_size, num_classes, max_len, y=None, prediction_only=False, shuffle=True):
        self.X = X
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.y = y
        self.prediction_only = prediction_only
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()


    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.X) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        #print("Generating batch with index {}".format(index))
        batch_indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        return self.__data_generation(batch_indexes)    

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.X))
        if(self.shuffle == True):
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes, )

    def __data_generation(self, batch_indexes):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        result = None
        batch_X = to_categorical(self.X[batch_indexes], self.num_classes, self.max_len)
        if(self.prediction_only):
            result = batch_X
        else:
            if(self.y is None):
                result = batch_X, batch_X
            else:
                batch_y = self.y[batch_indexes]
                result = batch_X, batch_y
        return result


from keras.layers import Input, RepeatVector, CuDNNGRU
from keras.models import Model

n_timesteps = np.max([x.shape[0] for x in X])
n_features = int(np.max([np.max(x) for x in X]) + 1)
latent_dim = 128

print("N timesteps {}".format(n_timesteps))
print("N features {}".format(n_features))
print("Latent dimension {}".format(latent_dim))

inputs = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
encoded = CuDNNGRU(units=latent_dim)(inputs)
decoded = RepeatVector(n=n_timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = CuDNNGRU(units=n_features, return_sequences=True)(decoded) 
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)

autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")
autoencoder.summary()

batch_size = 128
train_generator = batch_generator(X_train, batch_size=batch_size, num_classes=n_features, max_len=n_timesteps)
val_generator = batch_generator(X_val, batch_size=batch_size, num_classes=n_features, max_len=n_timesteps)

history = autoencoder.fit_generator(generator = train_generator,
                                    steps_per_epoch = X_train.shape[0]//batch_size,
                                    epochs = 2,
                                    #callbacks = [early_stopping, model_checkpoint],
                                    validation_data = val_generator,
                                    validation_steps = X_val.shape[0]//batch_size,
                                    #use_multiprocessing = True,
                                    #workers = n_cpu
                                   ) 

X_generator = batch_generator(X, batch_size=batch_size, num_classes=n_features,  max_len=n_timesteps, prediction_only=True ) 
compact_representation64 = encoder.predict_generator(generator=X_generator, steps=X.shape[0]//batch_size, verbose=1)
```

The problem is that each sample is encoded to the same fixed-length vector:

### SAMPLE #1

> array([-0.00898637,  0.02220072, -0.0095799 ,  0.00655961, 0.00733364,
>           0.00351852,  0.00088661, -0.00060489, -0.00819919, -0.01798768,
>          -0.02408937, -0.01549   ,  0.00395884, -0.0124888 , -0.00321282,
>          -0.01447861, ............................................

### SAMPLE #100

> array([-0.00898637,  0.02220072, -0.0095799 ,  0.00655961, 0.00733364,
>           0.00351852,  0.00088661, -0.00060489, -0.00819919, -0.01798768,
>          -0.02408937, -0.01549   ,  0.00395884, -0.0124888 , -0.00321282,
>          -0.01447861, ............................................

Comment: It looks odd, with your **RepeatedVector**, You use the output of your **first GRU layer** and repeat the same **n times** so that the **second GRU layer** takes a sequence of **n similar vectors**

Comment: Any possible reasons for that strange behaviour ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you want is:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
encoded = CuDNNGRU(units=latent_dim, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
decoded = CuDNNGRU(units=n_features)(decoded)
```

By adding the `RepeatVector` layer you create a constant sequence that is fed to the second `CuDNNGRU` layer. Hence the constant output.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my problem. I edited the post ;)